# Notifications in iOS 9 with iOS 10's UserNotifications framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsusernotificationcenter

Reading [here](https://github.com/ChenYilong/iOS10AdaptationTips) it suggests the UserNotifications framework should work fine on iOS 9, but `[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter]` is always nil for me on my iOS 9 device. Has anyone run into this issue..?

Comment: You can't use iOS 10 APIs under iOS 9. And no, that link doesn't say you can use the new APIs under iOS 9.

Comment: It compiles and largely runs fine (though crashed trying to add an image attachment to a notification) and from the link I posted it suggests the same code works on both iOS 9 and 10... Or am I just assuming incorrectly and really the guy is showing how iOS 9 used to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to use the old API for pre-iOS 10 devices, which is a pain. But makes sense really from a technical point of view, it just seemed from the link I posted that it was possible to use the same code on iOS 9 and 10 but when you look at his source code it does have OS version checks to use the relevant API.